# How can I manage a Prestashop website with GIT

Tags: mysql, git, prestashop

I have a website developed with Prestashop, the website is load-balanced and the last time I tried to add a module in prestashop, I was obliged to do it on each front server.

I don't want to do it this way because I can break the production if something goes wrong. I want to do it first on the pre production server before pushing it on the production server, but the problem is that I don't know how to do the same with the database.

Is there another way to host the full Prestashop in git?

Comment: You should get on google and learn GIT :)

Comment: i'am already using git , if the server was'nt load-balanced, i would have no problem but my developement environment is not the same than the production one so for now, i am making change on the prestashop on each front but when i will push a modification( in the GIT), it will erase all changes i have made

Comment: sorry for the english :)